# Angular Property with type interface throws an error on declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model like below

```
export interface IAdminUser {
  name: string
  role:string
  office:{
    department:string
    designation:string
  }
}
```

In my app.component.ts i am populating it via some data

```
 export class AppComponent {
      data = {
        name: "Admin",
        mob: 8888888888,
        email: "admin@gmail.com",
        role: '1',
        office: {
          department: "IT",
          designation: "Admin",
          code: "ADMIN123"
        }
      };

      adminInfor: IAdminUser = {};

      ngOnInit() {
        this.adminInfor.name = this.data.name;
        this.adminInfor.role = this.data.name;
        this.adminInfor.office.department = this.data.office.department;
        this.adminInfor.office.designation = this.data.office.designation;
      }
    }
```

I am getting error in below line

**adminInfor: IAdminUser = {};**

> // Type {} is missing the following properties from type IAdminUser; "
>   name, role etc

If i decalare it like this

```
adminInfor: IAdminUser = {
  name:'',
  role:'',
  office:{
    department:'',
    designation:'',
  }
}
```

I want to know is there any other efficient way to do it rather than initializing all keys with empty values.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize a variable as `{}` which is has a `Class/Interface` type.

In your case, `adminInfor: IAdminUser = {};` will definitely throw error due to compile time type checking.

Instead of `''`,  you can also initialize as:

```
adminInfor: IAdminUser = {
  name: null,
  role: null,
  office:{
    department: null,
    designation: null,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The properties of `type interface` `IAdminUser` are required, but in this line

`adminInfor: IAdminUser = {};`

you missed to initialize the properties.

Either initialize them or make them optional in the `type interface` like

```
interface IAdminUser {
  name?: string,
  role?: string,
  office?: {
    department: string,
    designation: string,
  }
}
```